# How to access the SVI of a switch through a IPSEC tunnel?

Tags: networking, vlan

I'm adding a new router, firewall and switch to our brand new site, and I'm scratching my head with the configuration of the SVI.

In the other sites, there is 4 VLANs on the switches:

- 1x VoIP (DECT) -> VLAN 8
- 1x User_Wifi -> VLAN 126
- 1x User_LAN -> VLAN 60
- 1x Guest_Wifi -> VLAN 20

Those switches have 3 trunks going to the firewall:

- 1x User_LAN (Gi1/0/1) -> letting pass VLAN 60
- 1x VoIP (Gi1/0/2) -> letting pass VLAN 8
- 1x Wifi for users (Gi1/0/24) -> letting pass VLAN 126 & 20

I manage those switches by giving the IP address of the VLAN 60, which is, afaik, not the best practice.
On each port of those switches, the native VLAN is the VLAN 60.

What I want to achieve is to create a new VLAN (VLAN 2 for example) dedicated to the management of the router, the firewall and the switch. This VLAN will have the 192.168.69.0/24 subnet attached, and can be accessed through our site-to-site VPN.

What I've done is to create a new VLAN interface who has the IP 192.168.69.3, and I made every interface of the switch a member of this VLAN (`switchport access 2`).

But now the problem is that every interface has access to the VLAN 2, which is not what I want. I only want our IT team to access it, and the rest of the users to acces the VLAN 60. And I need to keep the native VLAN of the 1st trunk to be the VLAN 60.

Thinking about it at a physical level, might it be a good idea to dedicate a physical interface for the management VLAN? And just plug it into one of the firewall interfaces like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the devices, make sure you've added the management VLAN and configured an IP address on that interface (SVI on a switch, L3 port or subinterface on a router).

If you add access ports to the management VLAN, hosts connected to those ports are directly connected to it - except for a quick service port you likely won't want that.

Instead, you can then either extend that VLAN to the admin workstations, either on a VLAN trunk or using dedicated links - both rather cumbersome and not possible over IPsec - or much simpler *route* into and out of the management VLAN (=connect the VLAN to a router or a layer-3 switch, and route packets between admin PCs and managed devices).

To restrict access to the IT team, you use an ACL on the router (or L3 switch) - for the management subnet as destination, you permit only source IP addresses from your admin workstations and deny all else.

Comment: I do not really understand what you mean by "routing" the management VLAN. On the remote site, there is no dedicated workstation to manage the switch, so it'll be done through the VPN. When I will route the VLAN (routing the .69 subnet through the VPN), it means I should have a physical management interface to access the switch? Otherwise, how will it go through a trunk?

Comment: I've tried to make my answer a bit clearer - had actually missed that you *must* route over IPsec. But routing is the better approach anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Zac67. I've finally chosen the approach of the physical management interface, which is way simpler to map on our schemes.